# Fijar columna en excel con php

Tags: php, excel

Tengo las siguientes lineas

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePane('A');
```

lo cual me da el siguiente resultado:
pretendo fihar la columna A pero creo que la linea de arriba no me lo permite

Answer (score 1):

El método que estás usando es incorrecto, sólo debes poner la siguiente línea.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4); // donde 0 es la columna desde donde se congela y 4 es la fila hasta donde se congela.
```

Te dejo esta guía si no comprendes la diferencia entre columna y fila : [Columnas y filas](https://exceltotal.com/columnas-y-filas/)